# What would cause extras.execute_values to timeout?

Tags: psycopg2

I'm seeing execute_values occasionally timeout on my database, even though it's only inserting about 500 rows. It's taking over six minutes to do this, and I've verified that inserting a subset of values works, and that there are no locks or other competing code. What could be causing this?

My code is:

```
def do_insert(connection, cursor, insights):
    if(insights is None or len(insights) == 0):
        raise Exception('User has no videos')
    columns = insights[0].keys()
    rows = [list(i.values()) for i in insights]
    sql = 'insert into tiktok_next.insights (' + ','.join(columns) + ') VALUES %s'
    values_statement = '(' + ','.join(map(lambda x: '%s', columns)) + ')'
    logging.info(f'inserting {len(rows)} insights rows')
    extras.execute_values(cursor, sql, rows, values_statement, 50)
    logging.info(f'executed')
    connection.commit()    
    logging.info(f'inserted {len(rows)} insights rows')
```

Comment: Did you finally figure this out?

Comment: Same issue here. Other operations using `execute` complete normally, but not `execute_values` for some reason.